# BIRT Theme not displaying on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6, birt

We have three distinct report themes defined with in a library, they all consist of header colors, text justification, text color, data sources, etc. We apply a theme to a report and the changes show up in the BIRT Web Viewer within Eclipse, but when we deploy our application that uses the BIRT viewer to Tomcat, the themes are no longer displayed.

We also have four data sources defined within the library that all the reports use, and those stay put after the deployment, it is just the CSS coming over that is ignored or dropped.

I have searched and searched for this, and the only thing I've found was an issue on stackoverflow from 2008ish.

Any thoughts, or suggestions?

Thanks,

Ian

Eclipse Indigo SR2
BIRT 3.7.1
Tomcat v6.0

Themes are defined as:

```
 ...
 <themes>
    <theme name="defaultTheme" id="2">
        <styles>
            <style name="table-header" id="6">
                <property name="backgroundColor">#660033</property>
                <property name="backgroundPositionX">left</property>
                <property name="fontWeight">bold</property>
                <property name="color">#FFFFFF</property>
            </style>
        </styles>
    </theme>
    <theme name="dccTheme" id="260">
        <styles>
            <style name="table-header" id="261">
                <property name="backgroundColor">#730000</property>
                <property name="backgroundPositionX">left</property>
                <property name="fontWeight">bold</property>
                <property name="color">#FFFFFF</property>
            </style>
        </styles>
    </theme>
    <theme name="mccTheme" id="263">
        <styles>
            <style name="table-header" id="265">
                <property name="backgroundColor">#005281</property>
                <property name="backgroundPositionX">left</property>
                <property name="fontWeight">bold</property>
                <property name="color">#FFFFFF</property>
            </style>
        </styles>
    </theme>
</themes>
...
```

Comment: I do not know what the BIRT Web Viewer is; but I don't think that this question has anything to do with Adobe Flex.  Am I correct?  If you found a related question, can you provide a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have defined the theme inside the library, if you have linked the CSS then you have to put even the CSS files inside the war that you deploy, if you want to avoid to put CSS files in the war you have to [import CSS files into the library](http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-themes-report-birt) .

When you set the theme that is enclosed in a library you have to specify the fully qualified name :

```
libraryname.dccTheme
```

Comment: Seems that is imported correctly, should work ... See my updated comment on how to set the theme .

Comment: The funny thing is, the themes work just fine in the report designer. But when I deploy our application to Tomcat, it just ignores the css.

I should add that the library and report are not in the same folder. The library is in the root reports folder, and then the reports are broken down into sub-directories.

Comment: You have to put the library in the same folder as the rptdesign or rptdocument otherwise it doesn't work ...